# Why are single type constraints disallowed in Python?

Tags: python, types, python-3.6

Suppose you want to constrain a type variable to implement a certain interface. You might write something like so:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Callable

T = TypeVar('T', Callable)

class Foo(Generic[T]):
    ...

>> TypeError: A single constraint is not allowed
```

Why is Python unhappy about this use of type constraints? [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#generics) and the [Python source code](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/master/src/typing.py#L511) are unhelpful in this regard.

Note: in my particular case I am interested in constraining a type variable to implement an abstract base class, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You’re looking for `bound`:

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Callable)
```

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar):

> a type variable may specify an upper bound using `bound=<type>`. This means that an actual type substituted (explicitly or implicitly) for the type variable must be a subclass of the boundary type, see PEP 484.

`TypeVar(name, *args)` means that the type has to be one of `args`, so all instances of `T` would just be replaceable by `Callable` if `T = TypeVar('T', Callable)` were allowed.

You should be able to see the difference here (though I didn’t actually try it, heh):

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Callable

T = TypeVar('T', Callable, bool)

class Foo(Generic[T]):
    value: T

    def __init__(self, value: T) -> None:
        self.value = value

class Bar:
    baz = 5

    def __call__(self):
        pass

f = Foo(Bar())
print(f.value.baz)  # doesn’t typecheck because f.value is only a Callable
```

Comment: Minor follow-up: do you have any idea how to access the constructor of the type bound to the type variable? Specifically, I want to call `T()` from within the generic class's `__init__`.

Comment: @alcorn: That’s not a typing-level operation, so I’m pretty sure it’s not possible/shouldn’t be done. You can have the consumer pass in the class, though, through a parameter of type `Type[T]`.

Comment: Ok I see, I'm falling into the trap of thinking about Python's type parameters as being comparable to the same feature in languages like C++/Java/C#, but in reality they are (at present) only useful for enforcing type constraints at run time: they can not stand in for actual values.

Comment: @alcorn a quick search gives https://stackoverflow.com/q/71113281/688080, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67757839/688080, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/69310382/688080.