# In mypy, what type signature do I write for a function that accepts a type and something of that type as an argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I've got this:

```
def gradient_descent(
  ...
  model_class: Type[Model],
  J: Callable[[np.ndarray, model_class], float],
  ...
):
```

I want this function to take in a class, and also a function that accepts an instance of that class. However, this gives me the error `Name "model_class" is not defined.`. I'm assuming that's because mypy doesn't have access to `model_class` at typechecking time.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't think so because that answer seems to have nothing to do with mypy.

Comment: That doesn't really matter; you're not getting as far as MyPy, this is a Python problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know my attempted (wrong) solution results in a Python error, but I still see the problem as a mypy problem. Perhaps I'm missing something, though -- how would I use the techniques described in that answer to solve my problem?

Comment: Ah, it's not quite that, sorry. It's still not a MyPy problem, though, you simply cannot reference other params like that *in Python*.

Comment: model_class should just be `J: Callable[[np.ndarray, Model], float]` no?

Comment: As an aside, ditch those commas. They are incorrect

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That type would work, but I want to type it more specifically than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a [generic type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics), e.g.:

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Model) 

def gradient_descent(
  ...
  model_class: Type[T],
  J: Callable[[np.ndarray, T], float],
  ...
):
```

Comment: Hmm, when I run this I get "'TypeVar' can only have a single constraint." The example gives two constraints, `TypeVar('T', str, bytes)`. It looks like it's functioning as a union type of the two? As opposed to declaring that type T is a subclass of Model.

Comment: @EliRose--REINSTATEMONICA ah yes; fixed, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50185096/3001761