# Call constructor of type parameter in generic class

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I'm writing a generic class over `AnyStr`, so allowing `bytes` or `str`.

```
class MyObject(Generic[AnyStr]):
   ...
```

Inside (multiple) methods of this class, I would like to construct the empty bytes or empty string object, `b''` or `''`, depending on the type parameter. How can I do this?

Comment: I have an answer in mind if the caller will know ahead of time whether they want a `MyObject[str]` or `MyObject[bytes]`, instead of having an `AnyStr` themselves that they forward to `MyObject`. Does that condition hold?

Comment: @MarioIshac it does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a base class with the shared methods applying to both `str` and `bytes` that take advantage of common behavior (for example, both `str` and `bytes` having length, or both `str` and `bytes` being indexable), and two subclasses providing implementations for the specific behaviors. To force the subclasses to provide those specific behaviors (such that `mypy` can assume a call to their specific methods would succeed in the base class), you make an equivalent `@abstractmethod` in the base class.

Here's how it all looks like:

```py
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC
from typing import AnyStr, Generic, final

class MyObject(ABC, Generic[AnyStr]):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def empty(cls) -> AnyStr:
        pass

    def __init__(self, data: AnyStr):
        self.data: AnyStr = data

    # Example shared method.
    def is_empty(self) -> bool:
        # Assume that for the sake of the example we can't do `len(self.data) == 0`, and that we need
        # to check against `empty()` instead.
        return self.data == self.__class__.empty()

class MyStr(MyObject[str]):
    @classmethod
    @final
    def empty(cls) -> str:
        return ""

class MyBytes(MyObject[bytes]):
    @classmethod
    @final
    def empty(cls) -> bytes:
        return b""
```

We make `empty()` a class method instead of an instance method because it doesn't depend on an instance with particular data to know what an empty `str` / `bytes` looks like.

Additionally, we make `empty()` a final method so subclasses of either `MyStr` or MyBytes` that want to further provide specific behavior don't get to change what is considered "empty" (as there is only one thing that can be considered empty).

All of above will typecheck under `mypy --strict`.

On the caller side, they would never instantiate `MyObject[str]` or `MyObject[bytes]` (in fact, `mypy` will prevent that, as we would want, because `MyObject` doesn't have an implementation for `empty()`). Instead, because you said in comments that caller will know ahead of time whether they want `bytes` or `str`, they instantiate `MyStr` or `MyBytes` directly.