# Python init object of generic type

Tags: python, generics, python-typing

Coming from a C# background and knowing its generic type approaches I'm now trying to implement something similar in Python. I need to serialize and de-serialize classes in a special string format, so I created the following two base classes, the first for single entity serialization and the second one for list serialization of that entity type.

```py
from typing import Any, TypeVar, List, cast, Type, Generic, NewType
import re

T = TypeVar('T')

class Serializable(Generic[T]):
    def to_str(self) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    def from_str(cls, str: str):
        raise NotImplementedError


class SerializableList(List[Serializable[T]]):
    def __init__(self):
        self.separator: str = "\n"

    @classmethod
    def from_str(cls, str: str):
        list = cls()
        for match in re.finditer(list.separator, str):
            list.append(T().from_str(match)) # <-- PROBLEM: HOW TO INIT A GENERIC ENTITY ???
            # list.append(Serializable[T].from_str(match)) <-- Uses base class (NotImplemented) instead of derived class
        
        return list
    
    def to_str(self) -> str:
        str = ""
        for e in self:
            str = str + f"{e.to_str()}{self.separator}"
    
        return str
```

Then I can derive from those classes and have to implement `to_str` and `from_str`. Please see the marker **<-- PROBLEM"**. I have no idea how I can init a new entity of the currently used type for the list. How do we do this in the Python way?

Comment: Python generics are a lot closer to Java than to C# - they're almost entirely there for static analysis. A lot of the information isn't available at runtime.

Comment: I am fairly new to Python. Is there a better approach? I think that the procedure that I try to realize is quite simple. A base class with two methods to derive from and a list of the same typed entities. There will be a lot of derived classes that must implement the base. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user2357112supportsMonica says in the comments, `typing.Generic` is pretty much only there for static analysis, and has essentially no effect at runtime under nearly all circumstances. From the look of your code, it looks like what you're doing might be better suited to Abstract Base Classes (documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html), tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/S_ipdVNSFlo)), which can be easily combined with `Generic`.

A class that has `ABCMeta` as its metaclass is marked as an Abstract Base Class (ABC). A subclass of an ABC cannot be instantiated unless all methods in the ABC marked with the `@abstractmethod` decorator have been overridden. In my suggested code below, I've explicitly added the `ABCMeta` metaclass to your `Serializable` class, and implicitly added it to your `SerializableList` class by having it inherit from `collections.UserList` instead of `typing.List`. (`collections.UserList` already has `ABCMeta` as its metaclass.)

Using ABCs, you could define some interfaces like this (you won't be able to instantiate these because of the abstract methods):

```
### ABSTRACT INTERFACES ###

from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from typing import Any, TypeVar, Type, Generic
from collections import UserList
import re

T = TypeVar('T')

class AbstractSerializable(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def to_str(self) -> str: ...

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def from_str(cls: Type[T], string: str) -> T: ...


S = TypeVar('S', bound=AbstractSerializable)


class AbstractSerializableList(UserList[S]):
    separator = '\n'

    @classmethod
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def element_cls(cls) -> Type[S]: ...

    @classmethod
    def from_str(cls, string: str):
        new_list = cls()
        for match in re.finditer(cls.separator, string):
            new_list.append(cls.element_cls.from_str(match))
        return new_list
    
    def to_str(self) -> str:
        return self.separator.join(e.to_str() for e in self)
```

You could then provide some concrete implementations like this:

```
class ConcreteSerializable(AbstractSerializable):
    def to_str(self) -> str:
        # put your actual implementation here

    @classmethod
    def from_str(cls: Type[T], string: str) -> T:
        # put your actual implementation here

class ConcreteSerializableList(AbstractSerializableList[ConcreteSerializable]:
    # this overrides the abstract classmethod-property in the base class
    element_cls = ConcreteSerializable
```

(By the way — I changed several of your variable names — `str`, `list`, etc — as they were shadowing builtin types and/or functions. This can often lead to annoying bugs, and  even if it doesn't, is quite confusing for other people reading your code! I also cleaned up your `to_str` method, which can be simplified to a one-liner, and moved your `separator` variable to be a class variable, since it appears to be the same for all class instances and does not appear to ever be altered.)

Comment: Thanks, I this seems to be what I was looking for. One little thing left: when running I get the python error ```S = TypeVar('S', bound=AbstractSerializable[Any]) TypeError: 'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable```. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Managed to get it running by changing class declaration of the List like this: ```class AbstractSerializableList(List[AbstractSerializable[T]], ABC):```. Note that type S is not required anymore

Comment: Thanks @TWP — typo left over from earlier version of my answer. It should have been `S = TypeVar('S', bound=AbstractSerializable)`. (You're correct that you don't *need* `S`, you can just use `T` for both classes, but using a bound `TypeVar` makes your type hints much more specific.)

Answer (score 0):

For now I found a *dirty* solution - this is to add a Type (constructor) parameter of the list entries like so:

```py
class SerializableList(List[Serializable[T]]):
    #                                           This one
    #                                              |
    #                                              v
    def __init__(self, separator: str = "\n", entity_class: Type = None):
        self.separator = separator
        self.entity_class = entity_class


    @classmethod
    def from_str(cls, str: str):
        list = cls()
        for match in re.finditer(list.separator, str):
            list.append(list.entity_class.from_str(match))

        return list
```

I wonder if there is a cleaner way to get the correct [T] type constructor from List[T] since it is already provided there?