# How to use constructor of Generic type

Tags: python, python-typing

How do I use the constructor of a python Generic typed class?

```
T = typing.TypeVar('T')

class MyClass(typing.Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, initialValue: typing.Iterable):
        self.values: T = T(initialValue)

test = MyClass[tuple[int]]([1, 2, 3])
```

In this case I am expecting `T(initialValue)` to be equivalent to `tuple(initialValue)` but instead I get an error. "Exception has occurred: TypeError
'TypeVar' object is not callable"

I guess that's not too surprising since that's not what typing was built for, but is there a workaround to accomplish this?

Comment: Try `self.values: T = initialValue`. Seems like you're trying to call a constructor from T as a method by doing `T(initialValue)` and it simply doesn't exists as T is not callable. Anyways, it seems like you don't need to declare a type for `values`, why do you feel that you need a generic type for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to take an explicit factory method. Type annotations only exist for compile-time purposes, and at runtime that `T` is *just* a `TypeVar`. Consider

```
class MyClass(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, initialValue: Iterable[int], factory: Callable[[Iterable[int]], T]):
        self.values: T = factory(initialValue)
```

Then call it as

```
test = MyClass([1, 2, 3], lambda x: tuple(x))
```

*Note:* It would be nice to just pass `tuple` as the second argument, but `mypy` seems to choke when converting that typename to a `Callable`. Other type checkers may be able to handle it; your mileage may vary.